# Using ssl with node mysql and Cleardb

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ssl, cleardb

I have a free ClearDB account that I got through Heroku (as a resource)

It gives me the

1. CA certificate
2. Client cert
3. Client Key

**These are all in `.pem` format**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ssl = {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('cleardb-ca.pem', "utf-8"),
    key: fs.readFileSync('cleardb-key.pem', "utf-8"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cleardb-cert.pem', "utf-8")
};

const cleardb = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"HOST",
    user: "USER",
    password: "PWD",
    database: "DB",
    ssl: ssl
});

cleardb.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('connected!');
});
```

This keeps throwing
`Error: 22928:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1929:`

and then the error stacktrace shows an Object like
`library: 'SSL routines', function: 'ssl_choose_client_version', reason: 'unsupported protocol', code: 'HANDSHAKE_SSL_ERROR', fatal: true`

The `SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported` error is the same exact error I get when I try connecting to this DB through the `MySQL` CLI.

I.e. `mysql --host=HOST --ssl-capath=. --ssl-cert=cleardb-cert.pem --ssl-key=cleardb-key.pem --user=USER`

**I'm able to connect through both `Node` and the CLI if I do not use SSL.**

Any idea what's going on here?

Should I really worry that much about using SSL? I've read that if the option for transport security exists, that you should elect to use it.